# Streamlining the vote to close homework option page

Tags: feature-request, homework-and-exercises, vote-to-close

This is a small point, but a lot of my vote to close choices have been about homework questions. 
Is it possible to have that homework option come up on the first page of the "Why should this question be closed", page,  rather than go to another screen to vote?

I have no idea of the split between  the reasons for closing votes, but I guess homework would be a significant number, again I appreciate that this is not a major issue, just a suggestion to save time, for possibly lots of users.

Comment: Upvoting not because I necessarily believe this is a feature request worth implementing, but it's a good idea to suggest, at least.

Comment: So your suggestion would save a single click?

Comment: @DavidZ my apologies for any hassle to reviewers for my previous continuous edit habit. Just to get it sorted out from now on, is a guideline  of 3 or 4 edits, say resulting from comments pointing out errors in my post, ok? Thanks

Comment: @count_to_10 yeah, maybe I'd put it like this: if you find that you're editing more than 5% of your posts more than 5 times, you're probably editing too much. The 5's are rough estimates, of course.

Answer (score 5):

All Stack Exchange site have the same primary options in the closing dialog: only the off-topic subgroup is site-specific. So, it's extremely unlikely that this request will be implemented.

As a surrogate, I suggest using my bookmarklet [Close as OT reason #1](http://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/#closeOT): just drag it to the browser toolbar, and you will be able to close homework questions with **one** click on the bookmark.

Bonus: it works in Close Review and Low Quality Review, too.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do.